# VueJs | Laravel | Vuejs Function not working inside a loop

Tags: laravel

i have an Error :

```
You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

This function :

```
         getID: function(invoicesnvs) {
           this.idd=invoicesnvs.id;
            },
```

Is not working inside this loop function:

```
        getRinvoicesnv: function () {
            axios.get('/getrinvoicesnv')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.invoicesnvs = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error);
            })
             },
created: function () {
  this.getRinvoicesnv()
  this.getTemplate()
}
```

In blade :

```
<tr v-for="invoicesnv in invoicesnvs">   
 <a type="button" @click="getID(invoicesnv)" ></a>
</tr>
```

Any help ? Thank you ! 
Note please that the function works only after executing another function existing in blade.

Comment: Where is `getRinvoicesnv()` called? This doesn't seem to be your full code.

Comment: Thank you for ur interest, i eddited post for you

Comment: This code still doesn't seem to be the problematic part. Do you have a calculated property somewhere? Or can you show us the full code of the component?

Comment: I have a computed to calcule total yes and other get /post functions